# What is the Python equivalent for the "merge" method in R

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas

I am converting a piece of code written in R to Python.
Please suggest how should I convert the merge functionality in R to Python equivalent.

```
testDataFrame<<- merge(df_A, dfTBHrchy[,c("child", "name")],by.x = "Account",by.y = "child",all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried first, because you will get the answer just 2 mins of google surf.

Comment: pd.merge(df_A, 
                  dfTBHrchy[,c("child", "name")],
                  left_on='Account',
                  right_on='child',
                  how='left')

Comment: But I am unsure of whether left outer join will be the right choice here.. This x and Y are confusing.

Comment: @jaideepsingh for that we have to see 2 sample dataframes and the expected output dataframe. Please include them in your question as text so we can copy and replicate

Comment: Here's a help page that may be useful to you: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html